# fopen won't open file, providing the full path via fgets

Tags: c, fopen

I need to open a file, providing the full path. I used the function fopen to open the file, this **works**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {

FILE *file;

file = fopen("C:\\Users\\Edo\\Desktop\\sample.docx","rb");

if (file == NULL) {
printf("Error");
exit(0);
}

return 0;
}
```

but what i really need is to let the user choose which file he wants, however this code does **not work** .

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 int main () {

 FILE *file;

 char path[300];

 printf("Insert string: ");
 fgets(path, 300, stdin);

 file = fopen(path,"rb");

 if (file == NULL) {
 printf("Error");
 exit(0);
 }

 return 0;
 }
```

I tried as input:

C:\Users\Edo\Desktop\sample.docx

C:\\Users\\Edo\\Desktop\\sample.docx

C:/Users/Edo/Desktop/sample.docx

C://Users//Edo//Desktop//sample.docx

*none of them works*

Comment: I assume when the user enters the full path, it's terminated in 
 a newline. According to the `fgets` documentation: *If  a  newline  is
       read,  it  is  stored into the buffer.* You'll need to **[get rid of the newline character at the end of the line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input)** to get a valid file name.

Comment: if you want to explore why this is not working (although @lurker is probably correct) use sysinternals procmon, it will show you all the file operations performed by your program and why they failed

Comment: By the way, you might wish to consider replacing `printf("Error");` with something line `perror(path)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fgets` leaves the newline on the end of your string.  You'll need to strip that off:

```
path[strlen (path) - 1] = '\0';
```

You'll need to `#include <string.h>` for this too.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @lurker, he told me what was the problem, I fixed the code this way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {

FILE *file;

char path[300];

printf("Insert string: ");
fgets(path, 300, stdin);

strtok(path, "\n");
file = fopen(path,"rb");

if (file == NULL) {
printf("Error");
exit(0);
}

return 0;
}
```